# Close mubsub client after emitting with socket.io-mongodb-emitter

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, sockets, socket.io

I'm trying to emit some message into a `socket.io` room using `socket.io-mongodb-emitter`. My problem is that, my script never exists, because it keeps a connection alive to `mongodb`.

Please check my examples below, and give me some advice, how can I make the script close `mongodb` connection and let itself exit.

**emitter.js** this script emits the message, the client gets it, but the process doesn't exit.

```
var io = require('socket.io-mongodb-emitter')("mongodb://localhost:27017/test");
io.in('someRoom').emit('someMessage');
```

**emitter-2.js** this script exits, but the client never gets the message.

```
var io = require('socket.io-mongodb-emitter')("mongodb://localhost:27017/test");
io.in('someRoom').emit('someMessage');
io.client.close();
```

**emitter-3.js** this one works perfectly, the client gets the message, and the process exits. But `setTimeout` is an extremely bad solution, there must be some proper way to let this process exit by itself.

```
var io = require('socket.io-mongodb-emitter')("mongodb://localhost:27017/test");
io.in('someRoom').emit('someMessage');
setTimeout(function () {
    io.client.close();
},100);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe use a callback to get an acknowledgement that the client received the message, then call the close function

server:

```
var message = "hello";
io.in('someRoom').emit('someMessage', message, function(data){
    console.log(data);
    io.client.close();
});
```

client:

```
socket.on('someMessage', function(message, callback){
    // do something with message here
    callback('message received');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the .emit's ability to receive an acknowledgement that the message was sent.

Do like so:

```
io.in('someRoom').emit('someMessage',function(){
    console.log('message was sent');
    io.client.close();
);
```

On Server you need to call the function when it is received.

```
  socket.on('someMessage', function (name, fn) {
    fn('received');
  });
```

Documentation [here](http://socket.io/docs/#sending-and-getting-data-(acknowledgements))